# Good way to implement transactional editing (commit/revert) when using WPF data bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, transactions

I have a fairly standard requirement — I need to be able to open a dialog where user can change values in data-bound fields, and then choose to click OK or Cancel, where clicking Cancel reverts the changes.

I've looked at `IEditableCollectionView`, `IEditableObject` and `BindingGroup`s, but they all seem to be meant for editing a single item at a time. My program provides a collection of objects in a list, user selects an item from the list and edits it using `SelectedItem`-bound `TextBox`es. Meaning that any number of items may be edited, including adding and removing them from the list, and **all** of those changes need to be reverted if he presses cancel.

At first I was simply making object backups through deep-copy (serialization) and restoring them on cancel, but now the objects must contain references to other, shared objects, making this approach problematic.

What's the best way to approach such a scenario without manually copying objects and/or values back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more thought on the matter, I have concluded that the best way, at least for small-scale implementation, is to write a "by value deep copy" method that copies values of objects fields and properties without replacing the objects themselves (so that any references to the edited objects remain intact even when data is restored).

For this purpose I have written the following extension method:

```cs
public static void CopyDataTo(this Object source, Object target) {
    // Recurse into lists
    if (source is IList) {
        var a = 0;
        foreach (var item in (IList)source) {
            if (a >= ((IList)target).Count) {
                var type = item.GetType();
                var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
                var newItem = assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
                ((IList)target).Add(newItem);
            }
            item.CopyDataTo(((IList)target)[a]);
            a++;
        }
        while (a < ((IList)target).Count) {
            ((IList)target).RemoveAt(a);
        }
    }

    // Copy over fields
    foreach (var field in source.GetType().GetFields())
        field.SetValue(target, field.GetValue(source));
    // Copy properties
    foreach (var property in source.GetType().GetProperties().Where(
        property => property.CanWrite && !property.GetMethod.GetParameters().Any()))
    {
        property.SetValue(target, property.GetValue(source));
    }
}
```

It's no silver bullet: it only works on objects of the same type, list items have to have a parametrless constructor and there is no way to control recursion depth. In addition, I haven't yet had a chance to test in any long-term or more complex scenarios, but so far it does what it should (copies values between objects) and can be used for a simple backup/restore scenario:

```cs
var backup = new TypeOfVariableToEdit();
data.CopyDataTo(backup);
var clickedOK = RunDataEditor(data);
if (!clickedOK)
    backup.CopyDataTo(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class would work Perfectly. It can save changes, go back (step by step) or revert all changes and many other features.
DataTable class has a nested feature that goes well with XML.

In case you're willing to save in a database then take a look at [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I had a look at `DataTable`s and will probably use them in a larger future project. For this app, though, it's an overkill, I'm still learning C# and WPF so I want to keep it small and straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is not to:

if you need these items, get a fresh copy of them from the database or whatever data storage, allow the user to make changes, and if they press cancel, just discard the changes. If they press save, save the data to the storage and then refresh your existing screens or whatever.

Comment: I'm using DataContractSerializer to store the object graph in an XML file. Reloading the entire graph every time any edit on any property on any object is revrted is how I did it at first, but once the data grows it could quickly become very expensive. So I want to avoid it and only read the storage on startup (and only save on pressed OK).